# Getting FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION with double quotes in regex

Tags: lightning-aura-components, developer-console, bug, spring17

[image: Failed to save undefined... Unterminated string... <code>/\"I want a double quoted string\"/g</code>]

As shown in the image, when trying to create a regular expression in a lightning component controller, the save from the developer console fails because of an error parsing the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to log a bug with this; it appears that the quotes do need to be matched in Spring 17, and this behavior also does not appear in Winter 16. For now, you *should* be able to escape one quote to bring the balance back. Here's an example of a broken regex in Spring 17:

```
    var r = /src="([^"]+)"/g;
```

Here's a way to fix it:

```
    var r = /src="([^\"]+)"/g;
```

I did a simple test to make sure the results still worked:

```
    var r = /src="([^\"]+)"/g;
    var d = "<img src=\"www.google.com\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" />";
    console.log(r.exec(d));
```

Output:

```
[0]: src="www.google.com"
[1]: www.google.com
index: 5
```

---

### Update

[Gordon Oliver](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/33418/gordon-oliver) has this to say about the issue:

> There are no known changes to the validation that would cause this, so we will open a bug and investigate to find the root cause.

Comment: Changed it to "escape the quotes". Hope you don't mind, but to me it made it clearer.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I was just about to notice that when you edited. Thanks for the edit, though, because I might have missed it for some time.

Comment: The regex was just an example, the problem is that this is valid and the developer console is preventing a save.

Comment: @EtienneRocheleau We would need a concrete example. However, I'm fairly sure that the problem is you have an unterminated string literal, as the error says. Can you provide a legitimate example?

Comment: @EtienneRocheleau For example, I just tried `var m = "\"I want a double quoted string\"";` and it saved just fine. We need something we can reproduce and diagnose.

Comment: @sfdcfox What you tested is not a regex though,
The case I tested was to extract the content of  `src=""` in an <img src="https://www.google.com" width="120px" height="auto"/> tag for example.

I tested with var myRegex = /src="([^"]*)"/
I know it's not the best but it still works in javascript, but won't be saved by the developer console.

Comment: And as I said, the problem is not the regex, the problem I have provided is that valid javascript code does not compile in the developer console.

Comment: @EtienneRocheleau Okay, I've found a concrete example... one sec.

Comment: @EtienneRocheleau I'm going to independently see if I can't get a bug logged for this. Sometimes, you may be able to work around it by escaping a single quote so that the balance is returned (see example), but this definitely needs to be fixed.

Comment: I've raised this directly with the team that owns the Lightning compiler bits and asked them to comment.

Comment: @DougChasman Thanks! This seems like it'll a pretty major bug if it gets to production.

Comment: There are no known changes to the validation that would cause this, so we will open a bug and investigate to find the root cause.

Comment: @DougChasman Thank you very much, as stated this is not a blocking issue since I can work around the regex issue, but I thought it important to raise the question!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a known bug, and it has a workaround, which is to use:

```
var r = new Regex("src=\"([^\"]+)\"/g");
```

instead of using the // syntax:

```
var r = /src="([^"]+)"/g;
```

I tried this on both Winter '16, and Spring '17, and both cases had the same exception for the expression syntax, and both were fixed using the new Regex syntax.

Comment: Ok thank you, I fixed it also by using 

`new Regexp()`

Which seems to work or by changing the regex to a different format that does not break the salesforce validation.

Comment: @Gordon Oliver I have used the above said workaround but I am getting `Uncaught Action failed: c:Graph$controller$handleActive [Unable to evaluate code at: components/c/activityfeed.js]` error when loading the page.This is my regex `var token = /d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g;`  Made it like this `var token = new Regex("d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'/g");`